# google adwords URL parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Im having an issue with utm parameters in Google Adwords. I have set up various utm parameters using the google link builder that all measure the various acquisition channels im using ie Facebook, onsite and Adwords. Here is the URL I am having difficulty measuring:

example.com/?utm_source=adw&utm_medium=adw&utm_campaign=adw

When I go to the URL (with the parameters) directly google analytics picks up my segment no problem. When I put the URL with parameters into Google Adwords though it doesnt seem to pick up the traffic under the segment set by the url parameters above. Its strange because the ad preview that it gives you in the ad settings shows a URL that points to the site with the correct parameters but im not sure if Google Adwords is stripping the parameters out when the ad is live.

I know that the ad settings has a Ad URL options section but the format doesnt seem to allow me to put in the parameters like I have them above.

My format is 
utm_source=adw

whereas theirs is
{_name}=value

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you not to enable autotagging in Adwords ?  That would give you better reporting (since you can link the accounts and import Adwords data to GA), allows you to use GA segments for remarketing audiences in Adwords and spares you the trouble of adding utm parameters to your urls.

Comment: I could do this yes but I want to make sure the right segment is setup. Is it right to assume that everything under the paid traffic segment has come from my adwords traffic?

Comment: If you enable autotagging the medium will be cpc (cost per click), the source google and campaign the campaign name from the Adwords Interface. Plus you will get reports on what people searched for when they clicked your ad. Clicks from your setup above will go into the "other" channel since "adw" is not a recognized traffic source (unless you change the channel settings in the admin section).

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas what the problem could be, cause your Parameters looking correct (I would also highly recommend to use auto-tagging and connect your AdWords Account to your Analytics):

1. You have the Paramater in the Field Destination-URL and a normal URL in Final-URL -> AdWords picks Final-URL
2. You have your URL with the Parameters as Final-URL in your Ads and a normal URL without Paramaters behind your Keywords -> AdWords takes Keywords

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is, you are diretly hitting this

```
example.com/?utm_source=adw&utm_medium=adw&utm_campaign=adw
```

and using following in adwords

```
example.com/?utm_source=adw&utm_medium=adw&utm_campaign={_name}
```

{_name} is your custom value track parameters and not provided by default, so you must explicitly set its value at campaign level.

available value track parameters can be found [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?hl=en)
And camapign name is not provided by default.